# How to run Selenium (C#) and NUnit running with linux server?

Tags: c#, linux, selenium

I have developed a Selenium application along with NUnit test library here is the list of the packages:

```
<packages>
  <package id="Dapper" version="1.50.2" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="NUnit" version="3.8.1" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="NUnit.Console" version="3.7.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="NUnit.ConsoleRunner" version="3.7.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="NUnit.Extension.NUnitProjectLoader" version="3.6.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="NUnit.Extension.NUnitV2Driver" version="3.7.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="NUnit.Extension.NUnitV2ResultWriter" version="3.6.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="NUnit.Extension.TeamCityEventListener" version="1.0.2" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="NUnit.Extension.VSProjectLoader" version="3.6.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="NUnitLite" version="3.8.1" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Selenium.Support" version="3.4.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Selenium.WebDriver" version="3.4.0" targetFramework="net452" />
</packages>
```

Now i discover that I need to run that on a linux server, how can I do this?

Comment: AFAIK, there is [no support](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/4106) for Selenium.WebDriver for `netstandard`. You can, however, remote test a browser instance on a linux _client_ through the WebDriver

Comment: the problem is that I discover now that has to be executed on linux because of integration with other system. So that is why I'm asking for something to make it executable in linux. Othewise I need to rewrite it in Java

Comment: The application has to run from a linux server? or you need to test browsers running on a linux server? If the application has to live in the linux server your best bet (possibly only solution) is to rewrite in java or possibly other languages. If  you merely need to test browsers in a linux environment i would suggest using selenium grid

Comment: @socalcheesehead The test need to be runned on a linux server. So nothing I need to rewrite it in java... thanks for the grid advice.

Comment: no problem, did that work for you?

Answer (score 1):

Sure, You can, just install MONO in your Linux server, and then use MONO for build your code and generate the DLL, then use MONO to run NUnit console that execute your test cases in that DLL.